# Symfony 2 customise value from database

Tags: symfony, format

When I use this command:

```
{{ news.getnewsid() }}
```

I get this:

**11112223333**

But I want to view it in this format:

**1111 2222 3333**

To add &nbsp after each 4th number.

This row have always 12 numbers.

I thing that the anserw is simple but I have no idea now how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the number_format filter of Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html
It should work when you define a space as thousands separator.
Edit: Sorry, not a good idea, since this will produce blocks with three chars.

The "slice" filter could be also used for this, but you have to output every number block separately.
The same with the "split" filter which outputs an array (and can be used, too).

You could also write your own filter in PHP, which I think is the best ida if you will use this more often in your application. 
Writing extensions for Twig:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html
- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be..

```
{{ news.getnewsid()|split('', 4)|join(' ') }}
```

but like @Johni says it's not at all reusable as you would have to remember this every time.

As well as doing this in a twig extension you could also do it in your entity like..

```
public function getFormattedNewsId()
{
    if (null === $this->newsid) {
        return null;
    }

    return implode(' ', str_split($this->newsid, 4));
}
```

Which could then be called anywhere in your application using either `$news->getFormattedNewsId()` or in a Twig template using `{{ news.formattedNewsId }}`.

Comment: I use this one by @Johni but this is also sollution for it. Thanks!